# Attempting to check if a list isn't empty AND some other condition within the same if statement

Tags: python, list, if-statement, typeerror

The easiest way to explain this is to show a simple example:

```
x = [0]

f = 4
if (x) & (f < 6):
    print("yes")
```

The idea is simple, check if a list contains any content and if some other variable is less than some number.

The solution yields the following error and I'm not entirely sure what the solution is.

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'list' and 'bool'
```

Comment: In Python, `&` stands for Bitwise And, a logical And is represented by `and`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`&` isn't the logical "and" operator in Python, it's the [bitwise and operator](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#binary-bitwise-operations). Instead, you should use the logical "and" operator, which is simply `and`:

```
if (x) and (f < 6):
    print("yes")
```

Answer (score 3):

`&` is the "bitwise and" operator, while `and` is the logical and operator.

The correct if statement is the following:

```
if x and f < 6:
    print("yes")
```

Note that the parentheses aren't necessary here. Also, in Python a non-empty list is evaluated as `True`, that's why you can use `x` instead of `len(x) > 0` which is also correct.